# Am I able to redefine a variable to the name of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {"England":1}

team2 = input("Second favorite: ")

print(team2["England"])
```

In this example, am I able to have the user define team2 as 'dict' then call team2 as a dictionary?  It isn't working and I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/########/Documents/  #####.py", line ###, in <module>
print(team2["England"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and what input are you providing?

Comment: So you when you ask the user for his second favorite team, you expect him to write "dict"? Wouldn't it make more sense for him to write something like "England", and then you can do `print(dict[team2]`)?

Comment: you should not do so many things you are doing in these 3 lines ...

Comment: This is an edited version of what I have, I'm running 3.3.2.  dict is actually BayernMunich or ManCity, something that the user would feasibly enter.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking how to let the user specify a variable in your code by name. That is rarely a good idea. What you want to do is better accomplished using a nested dictionary structure.  For example:

```
teams = {
            "dict": {"England": 1}
        }

team2 = input("Second favorite: ")

print(teams[team2]["England"])
```

I imagine you wouldn't actually use the name `dict` here but rather something that makes more sense to the user. However, this is a more or less literal translation of the code you posted.

Comment: dict is just an example, `RealMadrid ={'Spain':7, 'Brazil':1, 'Argentina':0, 'Cameroon':0, 'England':0, 'Chile':0, 'Portugal':3, 'France':2, 'Germany':1, 'Croatia':1, 'Uruguay':0, 'Belgium':0, 'Italy':0, 'Netherlands':0, 'USA':0, 'Colombia':0}` is the real one for one of the dicts, and I have many similar dictionaries.

Comment: Then you should do exactly what I suggested, and make a two-level dictionary structure. Those should not be separate dictionaries.

Comment: How do you put a dictionary in a dictionary? `dict = {'example' = name = {'foo':'bar'},` isn't working.

Comment: By "isn't working" do you mean "I forgot the closing bracket"?

Comment: @user2959139: The second `=` should be a `:`, too.

Comment: `teams = {
"Barcelona" : Barcelona = {'Spain':10, 'Brazil':3}` this won't work, what should it be?

Comment: To actually answer your question, a dictionary is simply a series of key-value pairs. The value can be another dictionary, which you write in the usual way.  For your example: `teams = { "Barcelona" : {'Spain':10, 'Brazil':3}, "RealMadrid": {'Spain':7, 'Brazil':1}  }`

Comment: You suggested I make a two-level dictionary structure, so I need to put 15 dictionaries in one big dictionary, and I can't get that to work, I get invalid syntax on the '='

Comment: There's no `=` in it. I updated my previous comment to have two teams in it so you can better see the format.